# How to prevent colorbar overlapping in the right y axis (matlab)

Tags: matlab, colorbar

First, I am new in matlab.

I have a scattered graphic having two y axes.

I wanted to use a colorbar at the east side of the figure, however, the colorbar is overlapping on the right y axis and label.

```
FigHandle = figure('Position', [1, 1, 1200, 1200]);
h1 = scatter(x,y1,30,z);![enter image description here][1]
ax1 = gca;
grid on
hold(ax1, 'all');
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor','k','YColor','k', 'fontsize',20);
hold(ax2, 'all');
h2 = scatter(x,y2,30,z,'Parent',ax2); 
t = colorbar('peer',gca);
colorbar('location','eastoutside')
```

1) I tried to reduce the width of the plot screen (not figure) so that I may have some space for the colorbar but it didnot work.

2) I tried to increase the width of all figure screen, but the plot screen is also increased, so nothing changed.

I tried several position adjustment codes but I fail to figure out the concept.

In summary, I want to find out a way out to reduce the width of the plot screen, so that there is sufficent space for colorbar.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Running your code I get `Undefined function or variable 'x'.` Can you make your example a working example, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually adjust the length of your X-axis  with `axis([XMIN XMAX YMIN YMAX])` or `xlim([XMIN XMAX])`, and expand `XMAX` until the overlap is gone.

Otherwise here is bit of code that will do the thing you want:

```
currentLimit=get(gca,'Xlim') %Get the X limit from your current (gca) axis

set(gca, 'XLim', [CurrentLimit(1),CurrentLimit(2)+0.1*CurrentLimit(2)]) %Set a new Xlimit for the current axis
```

Hope that works!